# php regex - remove only newlines which do not have space before or after

Tags: php, regex, newline

I need to cleanup texts which have invalid newlines added even within words, and valid newlines which are in between words so there is a leading or trainling space.

with php a try to remove those newlines from a multiline text which is enclosed by characters, meaning having not a space before or after.

```
$textbefore = "text has newlines in wo\nrds and normal newlines \n bewtween words and again in wo\nrds";
$textafter = "text has newlines in words and normal newlines \n bewtween words and again in words";
```

tried this

```
$pattern="/(.{2}\n.{1})/m";
```

I have tried all possible patterns but in best cases only the first occurence is matched.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Reversing the question slightly, is a newline character only "invalid" if it surrounded by text on *both* sides? What about if it is at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: I think you make the assumption that regular expressions know language. It is up to you to define a "word". Visually noticing a language pattern does not necessarily mean it can be translated into a regex, especially when it comes to "words".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this into the following regex:

```
$textafter = preg_replace( "/(?<=\S)\n|\n(?=\S)/", '', $textbefore);
```

Which states that it must find:

1. `(?<=\S)\n` - A newline that is preceded by a character that is not whitespace, OR
2. `\n(?=\S)` - A newline that is followed by a character that is not whitespace

When it finds either of these newlines, it replaces them with nothing (an empty string).

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/nhDN9) that this produces the string:

```
string(82) "text has newlines in words and normal newlines 
 bewtween words and again in words"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\s)\n(?!\s)/
```

it will match new line that does not have space before and after

[Live Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1gP)